# Python icon not showing anymore

Tags: python, user-interface, ipython

During the last days, I have realized that the python icon  created in the Dock when launching ipython is no longer launching (see example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36899610/what-is-this-python-icon)). This is problematic if I want to select any other application and then come back to my plot, since I can't click on the icon in the Dock (so I have to minimize a lot of windows until I reach it). I am using python 3.5 and running on OS X El Capitan.

I don't know when the issue appeared exactly, and it is hard to tell its origin since I recently updated XCode and the python packages through conda, but I was wondering if anyone has any idea of why this could be happening.

Answer (score 0):

If you manage your installations with using Homebrew, you can run `brew linkapps` in your terminal to recreate symlinks to them.

Comment: Thanks for the info! But in my case, the XCode update was done with the App Store, and all the python packages are managed via conda.